# Words to address young (male) people with?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, terminology

I am thinking about words, maybe used by older generations to approach a young man. And using some common word that also has some meaning along the lines of "young, handsome, lively, energetic or innocent boy". Which, basically, reminds the older generation of how they once were themselves. E.g. something like, "excuse me ...(young, handsome boy), could you carry that bag for me, please?"

Comment: "excuse me **son,** could you carry that bag for me please?"

Comment: 'Yo' is pretty common but it is perhaps more peer-to-peer, or hip older people

Comment: "Young man" and "young lady" automatically implies the person being addressed to is attractive: youth = beauty

Comment: @Mari-Lou A. I have no idea where you get that notion. Youth most certainly does not equal beauty.

Comment: @JATerroba   I assure you when you get to a certain age, you start admiring young people with different eyes. :)

Comment: Youth = beauty, is the bottom line to the question. And how, at the age older people start seeing this, they refer to younger people in a memory of the time they used to be so young (read: beautiful).

Comment: I'm not arguing that youth is or isn't an attractive quality, but saying that ""Young man" and "young lady" automatically implies the person being addressed to is attractive" is a bit of a stretch. Families tend to call their younger members those terms and I really don't think they're expressing attraction.

Comment: @JATerroba One can recognise and appreciate a thing as being beautiful without being attracted to it.

Comment: I don't know about you, but I know a lot of people who, despite being young, are in no way, shape or form, beautiful.

Answer (score 3):

**Sir** works. Coming from an old codger or an old lady, it throws them off their stride and gets their attention. Oddly enough, even millenials respond well to a little old-fashioned respect.

Answer (score 0):

*young man, whippersnapper, junior, lad, sonny*

Comment: I don't think 'Whippersnapper' will agree to carry your bags.

Comment: young man, used to be OK but since Harry Enfield http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2hgAsi8Ae4 'young man' is not quite the same.

Answer (score 0):

Squire

Added examples (Edited)
"Be a good squire and help me carry these bags?" (suitable before the act)
"You Sir, are a gentleman and a squire!". (exceeding expectations)

Addressing a young man as squire is complimentary, and was often used by older generations, *usually after the fact*. This is to say, if you were to *instruct* a young person as squire it would likely be taken as a condescending insult: E.g. "Squire, please carry my bags." would likely afford you a comment of "Who you callin' squire gov?" whereas after the fact it's a compliment of thanks. So something like "Ah you're a squire, many thanks." would be an entirely appropriate and complimentary form of thanks towards a young man - the connotation being: acting in accordance, worthy of a knight. Worthy of respect and a noble profession for a young man to pursue.

Historically, a young nobleman acting as an attendant to a knight before becoming a knight himself.

Comment: If he is wearing armor I would go with this one.

Comment: Calling someone _squire_ would indicate either that you think they're your manservant or that you think they're some kind of local dignitary in a rural town somewhere.

Comment: Coming from the UK (let's call it the old country), you can also address a barman for taking care of your drinks with "thank you squire" or "you're a squire, thanks." You are NOT referring to them as your "manservant", nor as a "rural dignitary" but as a "helpful lad". Perhaps a little viewing of Game of Thrones (squires don't wear armour) and some actual experience with older generations from the old country would assist with your ponderous remarks. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A quirky word to call the person is **Adonis**.  It may be a bit ambiguous so you could get away with saying it without sounding like you are hitting on the person.

> ▸ noun:  (Greek mythology) a handsome youth loved by Aphrodite, the
>   goddess of love
>
> ▸ noun:  any handsome young man

Another term, **stud** (Hey there stud, can you go grab my bags) is heavy on the flirting side.  I doubt a straight guy would say that to a straight guy.  And as mentioned in comments it might as well have a phone number attached to it.

And then I will offer a third term, **boss**.  [Definition #7](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=boss&page=2) pretty much sums it up.  It could be said to a cool younger male without sounding like you want to have sex with him.  This is heavy slang but understood by most.

> Them: Yo!
>   You: Hey boss, what's up?

Comment: I might describe someone as an Adonis, but I highly doubt I'd ever use it as a vocative unless his name actually _is_ Adonis. “Excuse me, Adonis” sounds quite… bizarre to me. “Excuse me, stud” sounds a bit odd too, but that's just because it's mixing registers, which is kind of the point here.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet -  I have heard "Excuse me, stud" many times in my life.  Not usually from the people I want to hear it from but I have definitely heard it.

Comment: I actually think _stud_ is a good answer to the question, but it is not often used together with phrases of politesse when addressing people you don't know. I might use it with a stranger, but sparingly and carefully, lest he take offence or think I'm trying to jump him.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - well Adonis is just funny.  It is like the quirky way to say stud.  If you are within 10-15 years of a younger male that you call a stud you might as well slip them your phone number too.  I am just following the constraints of the question.  Is it a polite way to address someone?  Sure.  Is it super forward?  Yes.

Comment: Definitely use "stud" for 100% of those occasions on which, were your addressee female, you would use "slut."

Comment: A stud is a horse that is kept for breeding or a man who is proficient sexually, one who gets the ladies. Calling a stranger _stud_ would put a weird sexual spin on things if you ask me. I would suggest _stud muffin_ instead. (Just kidding with that last bit.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my USA west coast point of view:

Use 'stud' if you really want 'handsome', but this could be seen as TOO complimentary.

Use 'kiddo', 'sport', 'junior', 'champ', and the like if you want to indicate they are young (and you are old).

Use 'buddy', 'man', or possibly 'dude' if you want a friendly, equalizing term.

Comment: Midwest here. I think `buddy`, `man`, and `dude` are all perfectly fine for male-to-male communication. They seem a bit strange for a female to address a young male as such. I think the female equivalent would be to exclude the term altogether (i.e. "Excuse me, could you help me...") or use `sir`. Given the context of older generations addressing younger, I think `young man` is the most appropriate here.

Comment: Think all of those except your last line were already discussed.

Answer (score 0):

If it's man addressing a young boy in a (perhaps overly) familiar way, we have **slugger**, **bud**, **buckaroo**, **champ**, **cowboy**, or **tiger**.

Older women can use terms like **hon** (**honey**), **bud** or **dear** with little risk of it sounding like a come-on.

Comment: People need to use buckaroo more often :)

Answer (score 0):

You could say something to the effect of "Hello handsome fella, would you mind helping me with my bag?" Or something friendly like that. This seems like a more polite way to address a young man while also being complimentary and respectful to him.

Answer (score -2):

"Excuse me, *kiddo*, could you carry that bag for me, please?"

> [kiddo](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kiddo): (used as a form of address) a young person

Other options are *champ*, *hero*, *looker*, *dreamboat*, and adjectival *gorgeous* and *handsome*.

> [looker](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/looker), [dreamboat](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dreamboat): a very attractive person

"*Excuse me, gorgeous/handsome, could you carry that bag for me, please?*"

> That being said, the safest, simplest way to address a young person without sounding either false, condescending or whatever to them is by a plain, though polite: "Excuse me, could you carry that bag for me, please?".

Comment: Those would all be somewhat rude to use to address someone you don't know. I would certainly take offence at being addressed as either of them by anyone but a peer.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet But the OP is looking for a term that has some meaning along the lines of "young, handsome, lively, and energetic person." Both "young gun" and "young buck" encompass these meanings.

Comment: Yes, but not in a very positive way. They are both very often used in a disapproving manner. And they're not words you'd use to address a stranger with if you don't want to come off as rude, or at least inappropriately crude in your humour.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet So, to your perspective, any forms of address that imply liveliness, energy, and vigor due to young age sound either little flattering or inappropriately crude?

Comment: Not necessarily, no. But the ones you chose here all do. (_Kiddo_ just because it sounds pretty condescending. One of those words friends can use, but strangers can't.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, I think it's a tricky question, as long as quite a lot of forms of address can be meant as compliments, but actually be perceived as offensive, condescending, equivocal, or just inappropriate. And so, I think the safest way to address someone you don't know is using a plain "Excuse me, could you carry that bag for me, please?".

Comment: Absolutely. Your subsequently added words (_looker_, _dreamboat_, _gorgeous_, _handsome_) are all quite safe, though. _Hero_ **could** be taken as condescending, but most likely not; and _champ_ could go either way. _Gorgeous_ and _handsome_ are the best of the bunch, I’d say, even if they don’t specifically say anything about the addressee being young.

Comment: An old man addressing a young stranger as "dreamboat" will almost certainly be regarded as either taking the piss or trying to proposition him.